Create different columns using rows
I have this
input











ob1
88
ticket1
information ticket1


ob1
88
ticket2
information ticket2



and I need to get this
output













ob1
88
ticket1
information ticket1
ticket2
information ticket2



I'm using pandas library and python, I dont know if is possible or not. Thanks in advance for any idea or examples
pivot_table(values=['Description','Ticket Number'], index='Subregion', columns=['Description','Ticket Number'], aggfunc='count')
    Report_new.reset_index(inplace=True)


provide your example in text table(not image) with columns(not only values)

You can group by the columns you want, convert the values to a list and create a new DataFrame.
Assuming this sample DataFrame
   a    b      c
0  6  foo  hello
1  9  bar  hello
2  6  foo  world
3  1  foo  world
4  1  bar  world
5  2  foo  world
6  8  foo  world
7  7  foo  hello
8  3  bar  hello
9  5  foo  hello

you can try the following
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# random data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
                  np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], 10),
                  np.random.choice(['hello', 'world'], 10)]), columns=list('abc'))

# groupby and convert values to list
grp = df.groupby(['b', 'c'])['a'].agg(list)
# create a new data frame
# you can reset the index if you want
new_df = pd.DataFrame(grp.tolist(), index=grp.index)



           0     1     2     3
b   c                         
bar hello  9     3  None  None
    world  1  None  None  None
foo hello  6     7     5  None
    world  6     1     2     8

